# Accessing virtual class through the pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, abstract

I have to design the specific architecture of the project. I got stuck while trying to create the pointer to the virtual class, and got Segmentation fault (seems my pointer was not assigned correctly). 
Below I included the draft of what I'm trying to do.

```
// Class A has to be pure virtual. It will be inherited by many classes in my project.
class A: 
{
public:
 virtual void myFunction() = 0; 
}


// Class B implements the method from the class A
#include <A.h>
class B: public A
{
public:
void myFunction(); // IS IMPLEMENTED HERE!!
}


// Class C creates a pointer to the class A.
 #include <A.h>
class C:
{
A *ptr;
ptr->myFunction();  //Here I want to run myFuction() from the class B.
}
```

How can I make a connection between those three, so I get the result I want.
I can't change the architecture, or simply omit any of the classes A, B or C.
Thanks for help!

Comment: `A* ptr = new B`? It seems you could use [a good book or two to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), to freshen up on C++.

Comment: All your declarations are wrong, this cannot compile. And `A *ptr; ptr->myFunction();`: `ptr` points nowehere so a segfault is somewhat expected.

Comment: _"seems my pointer was not assigned correctly"_ It wasn't assigned (initialised) _at all_!

Comment: Learn what [polymorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-c/) is in C++. Also try not to use raw pointers. In this case it seems like you can use [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: `// IS IMPLEMENTED HERE!!`: no it is not, it is only declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual calls allow to access a function from an object through a pointer or reference of a base type. Note that the object itself needs to be of the type that implements the functionality.

So, in class C you can have something like:

```
B b;
A *ptr = &b;
ptr->myFunction()
```

or

```
A *ptr = new B();
ptr->myFunction()
```

Either way, you need to create an object of type B, and assign it to a pointer of type A*.

Comment: Dear Paul,

Thank you very much for the kind and instructive response. The second solution was exactly what I was looking for!